# Remove an inputfield if I choose an option in the select before

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have this select, and I want that if I choose the option value="2" that the next inputfield of Shippment date disappears

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="reason">Reden van storing</label>
<select id="reason" name="reason" class="form-control">
<option value="1">Tijdelijk niet leverbaar</option>
<option value="2">Uit assortiment, niet meer leverbaar</option>
<option value="3">Minder artikelen beschikbaar</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Shipment date</label>
<input type="date" name="shipment_date" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul verzenddatum in">
</div>
```

Comment: you want to disappear it completely?? or just want to hide it??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I want to hide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#reason").change(function(){
  var valueoption=$("#reason").val();
  if(valueoption==2)
  {
    $("#shipdate").hide();

  }
  else{
   $("#shipdate").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="reason">Reden van storing</label>
<select id="reason" name="reason" class="form-control" >
<option value="1">Tijdelijk niet leverbaar</option>
<option value="2">Uit assortiment, niet meer leverbaar</option>
<option value="3">Minder artikelen beschikbaar</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Shipment date</label>
<input type="date" id="shipdate" name="shipment_date" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul verzenddatum in">
</div>
```

Comment: Where is OP's jQuery tag?

Answer (score 1):

Use eventlisteners to attact to page load and select change

Note I gave the div an ID

**vanilla JS**

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("reason").addEventListener("change",function() {
    document.getElementById("shipmentDiv").style.display = this.value==="2" ? "none": "block"
  })
  document.getElementById("reason").dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); // in case it was selected at load time
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="reason">Reden van storing</label>
  <select id="reason" name="reason" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Tijdelijk niet leverbaar</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Uit assortiment, niet meer leverbaar</option>
    <option value="3">Minder artikelen beschikbaar</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="shipmentDiv">
  <label>Shipment date</label>
  <input type="date" name="shipment_date" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul verzenddatum in">
</div>
```

**jQuery** toggle

```js
$(function() {
  $("#reason").on("change",function() {
    $("#shipmentDiv").toggle(this.value!=="2")
  }).change()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="reason">Reden van storing</label>
  <select id="reason" name="reason" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Tijdelijk niet leverbaar</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Uit assortiment, niet meer leverbaar</option>
    <option value="3">Minder artikelen beschikbaar</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="shipmentDiv">
  <label>Shipment date</label>
  <input type="date" name="shipment_date" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul verzenddatum in">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onchange event attribute to do that.
See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp) an example of how to use that.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also w3schools is a poor reference. Try MDN instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("#reason").change(function(){
  var valueoption=$("#reason").val();
  if(valueoption==2)
  {
    $("#shipdate").hide();

  }
  else{
   $("#shipdate").show();
  }
});
</script>
```

```
<div class="form-group" id="shipdate">
<label>Shipment date</label>
<input type="date" id="shipdate" name="shipment_date" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul verzenddatum in">
</div>
```

Comment: Where is OP's jQuery tag?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery `hide` and `show` method for this.

html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="reason">Reden van storing</label>
    <select id="reason" name="reason" class="form-control" id="reason">
        <option value="1">Tijdelijk niet leverbaar</option>
        <option value="2">Uit assortiment, niet meer leverbaar</option>
        <option value="3">Minder artikelen beschikbaar</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="date_info">
    <label>Shipment date</label>
    <input type="date" name="shipment_date" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul verzenddatum in">
</div>
```

script

```
$('#reason').on('change', function(){
    var reason = $('#reason').val();
    if (reason == 2) {
        $('#date_info').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#date_info').show();
    }
});
```

> look for the id's in the html

Comment: Where is OP's jQuery tag?

Comment: there's none. but as i mentioned in my answer op can use jQuery. i think nothing is wrong here. peace :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an event listener and validate the selected value.

```js
const reason = document.querySelector('#reason').addEventListener("change", () => {
  const result = document.querySelector('input.form-control');
  if (document.getElementById("reason").selectedIndex == 1) {
    result.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    result.style.display = "inline-block";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="reason">Reden van storing</label>
  <select id="reason" name="reason" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Tijdelijk niet leverbaar</option>
    <option value="2">Uit assortiment, niet meer leverbaar</option>
    <option value="3">Minder artikelen beschikbaar</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Shipment date</label>
  <input type="date" name="shipment_date" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul verzenddatum in">
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan is adjusted now